# How do I use a VIM plugin without adding it to the package.json file?

Tags: npm, vim, plugins, eslint

I'm the only one on my development team that uses VIM. I want to use the eslint-plugin-prettier plugin, but I don't see how to use it without adding it to the package.json file, which seems like then others on my team would be forced to install it on their machines.

Answer (score 0):

Because JavaScript doesn't have an official style guide and can be quite wild in terms of accepted syntaxes, what tools to use and what rules to follow are to be defined at the project level. In concrete terms, the rules must be set in some configuration file inside the project and enforced by tools that are part of the project's dependencies and integrated, in one way or another, to the editor/IDE used by *every* contributor. Any other scheme is going to cause inconsistencies down the line.

Ideally, you would have a low-level, machine-readable `lint` script in your `package.json` that does what it has to do with the rules laid out in some project-local configuration file or another and can be called by any editor/IDE, a `format` script that works the same, and so on, in a transparent way: without any contributor having to even think about what "linting" or "formatting" does under the hood.

In this specific case, the fact that that package is not in the project's development dependencies means a) that the team didn't agree on its use, b) that you would be the only one using it, and c) that you shouldn't introduce it on your own, let alone force everyone in the team to install it without some kind of prior discussion.

If your team already uses Prettier and Eslint separately, be a good citizen and do the same. In Vim, the basic setup would look like this:

```
" In after/ftplugin/javascript.vim
" Prettier integration
set formatprg=npx\ prettier\ --stdin-filepath\ %

" Eslint integration
compiler eslint
```

which would let you do `gq{motion}` to format using Prettier and `:make %` to lint with Eslint. If you want to automate it all, consider using `:help autocommands'.

Answer (score 0):

You can restore `package.json` and `package-lock.json` after `npm install`. After all, the two files are just records.

```
# Make sure nothing to commit, working tree is clean
git status

# Then
npm install eslint-plugin-prettier
git checkout packge.json package-lock.json
```